# JSON to CSV conversion via JQ command in bash

Tags: json, bash, csv, unix, jq

Want to convert a json into CSV file. CSV file require all the Line Item Object 1 per line + that line should also contain PURCHASEORDERNO.

Trying to access the object PURCHASEORDERNO of the HEADER array from the LINE ARRAY by using .HEADER[].PURCHASEORDERNO. But getting error jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over null (null)

**JQ command :-**

```
echo '{"RECEIPT":{"HEADER":[{"LINE":[{"ITEMCODE":"CF7219","QUANTITY":"6"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7223","QUANTITY":"8"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7223L","QUANTITY":"8"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7419","QUANTITY":"6"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7119","QUANTITY":"3"},{"ITEMCODE":"AP7119/7219L","QUANTITY":"4"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7620","QUANTITY":"6"},{"ITEMCODE":"HP7313","QUANTITY":"40"}],"SUPPCUSTNAME":"CONFOIL CONTAINERS","SUPPCUSTCODE":"CON001","PROCESSDATE":"20190321","PURCHASEORDERNO":"P6254"},{"LINE":[{"ITEMCODE":"CF7219","QUANTITY":"6"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7223","QUANTITY":"8"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7223L","QUANTITY":"8"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7419","QUANTITY":"6"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7119","QUANTITY":"3"},{"ITEMCODE":"AP7119/7219L","QUANTITY":"4"},{"ITEMCODE":"CF7620","QUANTITY":"6"},{"ITEMCODE":"HP7313","QUANTITY":"40"}],"SUPPCUSTNAME":"CONFOIL CONTAINERS","SUPPCUSTCODE":"CON001","PROCESSDATE":"20190321","PURCHASEORDERNO":"P6254"}]}}'
 | jq -r '.RECEIPT.HEADER[].LINE[] | ["","ANCPACMEL","ADS",.HEADER[].PURCHASEORDERNO,"",.ITEMCODE,.QUANTITY,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]|@csv'
```

**Error:-**

jq: error (at :1): Cannot iterate over null (null)

**Desired Output:-**

```
#CustomsEntryNo,ClientCode,Warehouse,Reference,ArrivalDate,ProductCode,Quantity,QuantityUQ,Pallets,Location,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,ExpiryDate,PackingDate,CustomsEntryLineNo,CustomsEntryDate,CustomsAddInfo,CustomsQty,CustomsUQ,CtryOfOrigin,ValueForDuty,BondedWhsQty,BondedWhsUQ,TILV,CustomsSecondQuantity,CustomsSecondUnitQty,Tariff,PrimaryPreference,CustomsThirdQuantity,CustomsThirdUnitQty,ManufacturerCode,ZoneStatus,IsFromOtherFTZWarehouse,OutwardType,OutwardType
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,CF721911,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,CF722311,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,CF7223L11,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,CF741911,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,CF711911,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,AP7119/7219L11,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,CF762011,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62541,,HP731311,40,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,CF7219,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,CF7223,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,CF7223L,8,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,CF7419,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,CF7119,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,AP7119/7219L,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,CF7620,6,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ANCPACMEL,ADS,P62542,,HP7313,40,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: There's no question here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem. At the moment we are a bit puzzled if you have a question or if you just wanted to provide a solution to a problem. If you wanted to do the latter, please update the question such that it clearly represents a problem, and then add an answer yourself. Please have a look at [ask] and don't be afraid to take the [tour].

Comment: The input does not match your desired output. The input contains two times the same "PURCHASEORDERNO` "P6254". But your desired output contains two different numbers: "P62541", "P62542".

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the `PURCHASEORDERNO` in a variable in order to add it to each row.

```
jq -r '.RECEIPT.HEADER[] | .PURCHASEORDERNO as $pono | .LINE[] | [ $pono, .ITEMCODE, .QUANTITY ] | @csv' input
```

Update with header:

```
{
  echo '#Reference,ProductCode,Quantity'
  jq -r '.RECEIPT.HEADER[] | .PURCHASEORDERNO as $pono | .LINE[] | [ $pono, .ITEMCODE, .QUANTITY ] | @csv' input
} > output
```

Comment: How can I add header to it

Comment: @Prabhjot209 Use `echo` or `printf` before `jq`.

Comment: Thanks ceving, Trying it with the following but not getting the header.  echo "#CustomsEntryNo,ClientCode,Warehouse,Reference,ArrivalDate,ProductCode,Quantity,QuantityUQ,Pallets,Location,Attribute1,Attribute2,Attribute3,ExpiryDate,PackingDate,CustomsEntryLineNo,CustomsEntryDate,CustomsAddInfo,CustomsQty,CustomsUQ,CtryOfOrigin,ValueForDuty,BondedWhsQty$" | jq -r '.RECEIPT.HEADER[] | .PURCHASEORDERNO as $pono | .LINE[] | ["","ANCPACMEL","AFS DANDENONG SOUTH", $pono,"", .ITEMCODE, .QUANTITY ,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""] | @csv' test1.json

Comment: Don't pipe the header into `jq`. This are two commands each generating output. Put a semicolon in between or a newline.

Comment: I want to put the output including header into a file. As I have to transfer the file.